# Permission denied in a directory in Centos6.9

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, size

I have a directory in /mnt/vol1 , named home.

```
[root@myserver ~]#ls -tlrh /mnt/vol1/
total 510M
drwxrwxrwx  2 user1     user1  16K May 15  2018 lost+found
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user1     user1 510M Nov 30  2018 my_backups
drwxrwxrwx  3 root     root 4.0K May 12 11:25 others
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root        0 May 12 12:47 home
```

I can create new files or directories in /mnt/vol1 by root user, but not in /mnt/vol1/home.

```
[root@myserver ~]# touch /mnt/vol1/test
[root@myserver ~]# touch /mnt/vol1/home/test
touch: cannot touch `test': Permission denied
```

Below is the output of stat command on home.

```
[root@myserver ~]# stat /mnt/vol1/home
  File: `home'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 85354       Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-12 12:47:39.399000023 +0530
Modify: 2020-05-12 12:47:30.523000022 +0530
Change: 2020-05-12 11:34:16.379000021 +0530
```

The blocks are 0, and so is size. What does it mean? I cannot even move/delete this directory.

[update1]
I did this, but still caan't create a file.

```
[root@myserver home]# ls -lRa /mnt/vol1/home/
total 4.0K
drwxrwxrwx 7 shopclue shopclue 4.0K May 12 12:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root        0 May 12 14:31 .

[root@myserver home]#  chown root.root ..


[root@myserver home]#  ls -lhta
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 May 12 14:31 .
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 4.0K May 12 12:53 ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file `/mnt/vol1/home/test` present? Perhaps inside the directory `/mnt/vol1/home` are files that are not owned by root. 
Could you do a `ls -lRa /mnt/vol1/home/` to figure this out?

Also, does this filesystem happen to be NFS? NFS requires some 'special attention' when it comes to setting file permissions.

Comment: Updated my question with the output. Not NFS but yes the home directory is used as parent home for NIS users. This server is one of many clients.

Comment: @P_ptr, very strange! perhaps you can use 'strace' to debug the 'touch' error that you get. ```yum install strace``` and then strace touch ```/mnt/vol1/home/test```